# Unrecognized field "auth-server-url" trying to use Keycloak AuthzClient

Tags: java, keycloak

Getting error message: Unrecognized field "auth-server-url"

org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "auth-server-url" (Class org.keycloak.authorization.client.Configuration), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.BufferedInputStream@7e1a5ac5; line: 3, column: 23] (through reference chain: org.keycloak.authorization.client.Configuration["auth-server-url"])

the error occurs as I try to use org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient

AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create();

as en extra note, it is being used as part of a Spring Boot server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My versions were mismatched! 4.3 on keycloak server but I was using an earlier keycloak-authz client! This caused the error. I made sure the versions matched then the error went away.